# How to create and add table to predefined pdf template using Itext?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a predefined Template and i want to create and add table to 3rd page of template. Is it possible to do so?There are lot of option for creating new pdf using itext but i haven't seen any example where modifying existing pdf and adding table  to it is provided. Code example will be highly appreciated.

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("BCC Statements-Template.pdf");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("test.pdf");
    try {   

        PdfStamper stamper= new PdfStamper(reader, fileOutputStream);           
        PdfContentByte overContentByte = stamper.getOverContent(3);
        PdfPTable pdfPTable = new PdfPTable(4);
         pdfPTable.setTotalWidth(40);
            //Create cells
            PdfPCell pdfPCell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1"));
            PdfPCell pdfPCell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2"));
            PdfPCell pdfPCell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3"));
            PdfPCell pdfPCell4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 4"));
            //Add cells to table
            pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell1);
            pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell2);
            pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell3);
            pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell4);
            pdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(1, 1, 110, 150, overContentByte);
            stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `PdfStamper` for that. The code goes like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(1);
PdfPTable table = ...;
//add data to table
table.writeSelectedRows(... , canvas);
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: I am not able to see any table using the code.Please have a look at the code

Comment: This code is meant for you to fill the blanks, you are the one that knows what the table will look like. What information is missing?

Comment: Increase the table width, 40 is too small, and `pdfPTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 110, 150, overContentByte);`